# Bound on $\mathbb E\exp(\|S_n\|_1^\alpha)$ for some $d$-dimenstion random walk

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-walk

Let $0<\alpha<1$. I'm trying to find a bound on  $\mathbb E\exp(\|S_n\|_1^\alpha)$ for some random walk $S_n$ on $\mathbb Z^d$. I already proved that we can bound $\mathbb P(\|S_n\|_1=k)\leq 2d\exp(-\beta k^2/n)$ for some $\beta>0$, and also the weaker result $\mathbb P(S_n=x)\leq 2d\exp(-\beta \|x\|_1^2/n)$.

I'm then asked to prove that for any $\epsilon>0$ we eventually have $$\mathbb E\exp(\|S_n\|_1^\alpha)\leq\exp(n^{\frac1{2-\alpha}+\epsilon}).$$ As a hint I was given to use that for $a_1,a_2,a_3,c>0$ and $a_2<a_3$ we have for large enough $m$ that $$m^{a_1}\exp(m^{a_2}-cm^{a_3})<\exp(2m^{a_2}-cm^{a_3})<\exp(-\frac c2m^{a_3}).$$ Expanding, this gives something like $$\mathbb E\exp(\|S_n\|_1^\alpha)=\sum_{k=0}^n\mathbb P(|\tilde S_n|=k)\exp(k^{\alpha})\leq 2\sum_{k=0}^n\exp(k^\alpha-\frac\beta nk^2).$$ Here we have simplified by noting that $\|S_n\|\stackrel{\mathcal D}=|\tilde S_n|$ where $\tilde S_n$ is a simple random walk in one dimension. Now it suffices to prove for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists an $N$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $$2\sum_{k=0}^n\exp(k^\alpha-\frac\beta nk^2)\leq\exp(n^{\frac1{2-\alpha}+\epsilon}).$$

I can't see how to proceed from here. It seems that somehow we have to fit the $\exp(k^\alpha-\frac\beta nk^2)$ term in the given exponential inequalities, but I have the feeling I'm missing some step. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What typical values of $\alpha$ are you interested in? It seems that this upper bound is pretty bad when $\alpha$ is small (especially when $\alpha=0$?). I would tend to predict that since $\lVert S_n\rVert_1$ is roughly $n$-subgaussian, $E(\exp(\lVert S_n\rVert_1^\alpha))$ should behave like $\exp(n^{\alpha/2})$ instead

Comment: Thank you. The typical values are $0<\alpha<1$.

Comment: The inequality does not hold for all $\beta>0$. So do you mean we only need to prove it for some $\beta$?

Comment: In this context, we should suppose that $\beta>0$, but we don't know it's particular value. However, I just found that there might be much simpler solution, and that the approach I started above does not work, as you indicate by your comment. Maybe you can verify.

We know that $\|S_n\|_1\leq n$, so using $\alpha<\frac1{2-\alpha}$, which holds for $\alpha<2$, so certainly for $\alpha\in(0,1)$, we have $\mathbb E\exp(\|S_n\|^\alpha)\leq\exp(n^{\alpha})\leq\exp(n^{\frac1{2-\alpha}})$. Unless I'm overlooking something, I suppose that I do not need the hint or any nonelementary bounds at all

Comment: That new proof in the comment above looks correct to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I indicated in the comments, since $\|S_n\|_1\leq n$, and since for any $\alpha<2$ we have $\alpha<\frac1{2-\alpha}$, it follows that $$\mathbb E\exp(\|S_n\|_1^\alpha)\leq\exp(n^\alpha)\leq\exp(n^{\frac1{2-\alpha}}).$$ Hence for all $\epsilon>0,n\geq N=0$ implies $$\mathbb E\exp(\|S_n\|_1^\alpha)\leq\exp(n^{\frac1{2-\alpha}+\epsilon}).$$ Following the approach as was hinted is not necessary.